# creating multiplie files in python

Tags: python

I was trying to make program in python that makes multiplie files fe. from number 2 to 10 so it would make something like this ex2.py ex3.py ex4.py etc until 10, but it creates only first in this example ex2.py and i dont know how to change that

```
import os

x = int(input("First exercise: "))
y = int(input("Last exercise: "))

    for z in range(x, y):
        i = str(z)
        filenames = [input()]

        for filename in filenames:
            open("python/"+filename+i+".py", "a")
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `input()` there?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
# x = int(input("First exercise: "))
x = 2
# y = int(input("Last exercise: "))
y = 10

# from x to y step 1
for i in range(x, y + 1):
    # one file name
    filename = input("filename:")

    # file path
    path = f"python/{filename}{i}.py"

    # create it and do nothing
    with open(path, "w+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        pass
```

or i think you want this:

```
# x = int(input("First exercise: "))
x = 2
# y = int(input("Last exercise: "))
y = 10

# just one file name
filename = input("filename:")

# from x to y step 1
for i in range(x, y + 1):
    # file path
    path = f"python/{filename}{i}.py"
    print(path)

    # create it and do nothing
    with open(path, "w+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        pass
```

out

```
filename:ex

python/ex2.py
python/ex3.py
python/ex4.py
python/ex5.py
python/ex6.py
python/ex7.py
python/ex8.py
python/ex9.py
python/ex10.py
```

Comment: yeah that what i wanted ;P

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for filename base (variable filenames) outside the for loop so it doesn't ask for it every time. Other than that, the script works fine.

Actually one more thing, setting x = 2 and y = 10 will produce files from 2 to 9.

Comment: that worked thanks
and thanks for reminding under:
''' y = int(input("Last exercise: ")) '''
i added
``` y = y + 1 ```